# How easy is it to replace this drywall and change the plumbing?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, drywall

This is our first major renovation, and we're doing a full refresh on our upstairs bathroom! Right now though, before we get the walls tiled, we're looking to replace the plumbing in the wall up to the shower head. The way it was set-up before was the tube was coming from the spout, and we just want to clean things up a bit.

I feel like this shouldn't be that difficult of a job, but it's definitely nothing I've done before, so trying to gather as much info as I can before I start ripping more out lol

[image]

Comment: "How easy" is the definition of a subjective thing, and therefore off topic here. It's also almost comically vague. We have no idea what's in that wall. Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Are you replacing the tub too?

Answer (score 1):

It is relatively easy to remove the drywall around the tub. It has to be done in order to remove the tub.

First score deeply along the corner and across the top at the ceiling.
Then score from the ceiling to the floor. The distance from the corner is dependent on your plan for the entire bathroom:

1- If you are tearing out all the walls, just make a score anywhere past the tub.

2- If the plan is to just take out the walls needed to get the tub out, score a straight line about 2 inches out from the outer edge of the tub from floor to ceiling.

3- If the plan is to install a larger tub or a freestanding tub with tile on the walls, score the width of the new tub =2 inches...OR 36 inches out from the corner. (durarock is 36" x  60")  This makes it the right dimension to install your tile backer.

Use a hammer to knock some holes large enough to get your gloved hand in and pull.  It would make sense to knock the holes away from where you know the plumbing is.  You will probably be surprised how easily the drywall gives up.
Once a few pieces are removed you will be able to see in the wall and continue while being aware of what is inside.

Clean up any nails or screws, and you have access to the plumbing and you can remove the tub once the drain is disconnected. Proceed according to the plan for your new tub. ( unknown to us)

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

If you are not replacing the tub, protect it well. Surface damage and things that should not go down the drain are both concerns with active demolition over a tub.

If you are replacing the wall surface around the tub, and intending tile finish, choose tile backer board, not drywall. It's a very small increment in the overall cost of the job, and provides a much more secure base for the expensive (both cost and labor) tile on top of it.

It's a fairly straightforward job. While you have the walls open, consider placing and documenting some additional framing for potentially adding grab bars at some future point in time. You may also discover other things needing to be addressed when you open the walls up, but that's just part of remodelling.

Comment: Thanks for the info! We do plan to replace the tub, we just haven't pulled it out yet. And we're tiling the walls around the tub afterwards.

Comment: Just be cognizant of the material the water pipes are made of.  If the existing ones are galvanized, and your new work is going to use copper, your need to use galvanic isolation couplers between the old and new.  If the new work is going to be CPVC or PEX, then the dissimilar materials is not as much of an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Opening the wall, changing some pipes and replacing the wall board is not "hard" but there are a HUGE number of small, easy things you will have to learn.  If you learned them one at a time, I would say that each one of them is an easy DIY project suitable for beginners.  But if you've really never done anything relevant before, yuou'll be doing a lot of reading, asking a lot of questions, making A LOT of repeat trips to the store to buy parts and exchange the wrong ones you bought.

So I suggest you be guided by this:

1. Are you eager to learn?  Will that by itself reward you?  If not ... don't start your DIY career with this one.
2. Are you able to live without this tub/shower for an indefinite time?  I don't mean forever, but if it's two weeks, two months, .... is that ok?  If not ... don't start with this project.
3. Does this tub/shower or at least this room have its own shutoff valve, and do you have another bathroom?  This is so that you can make mistakes with the plumbing, learn and fix them, while the rest of your house has water.   You don't want this project to force your family into a hotel.

If your answer to any of the above questions is the wrong answer, you could perhaps do this:

- Demolish and discard the wallboard
- Get a plumber to add a room-specific pair of shutoff valves, *if possible*, ie if there is access perhaps in the basement to a pair of pipes that serve only this room.
- Research and purchase the replacement taps, shower head, etc.
- Get your plumber to do the rough-in
- Install the new wallboard -- but get your tiler to choose it before you buy.
- Install the taps/shower heads/ etc after tiling.
- Do the grouting?  If you want
- Do the silicone?  If you want
- Paint the ceiling?  Yes, you got this!

I think if you bite off the above you will learn a lot, save a little money and the job will get done relatively quickly with MUCH less risk.